# IHttpRequest response length limit

Tags: c++, http, unreal-engine4

I have an HTTP game server that I am setting up and I have one function that returns a lot of information about the map. The output from the server is about 7800 characters long, but when I get the contents of the URL in the game, the game only gets 1124 characters.

Is there a limit on the length of the response content of an IHttpRequest?

Pertinent code:

```
FString ANetwork::getContentsOfURL(FString URL, TArray<FString> keys, TArray<FString> values)
{
    serverResponse = NULL;

    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest> HttpRequest = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
    HttpRequest->SetHeader(TEXT("Content-Type"), TEXT("application/json"));

    int32 count = keys.Num();
    URL += "?auth=" + authenticator;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        URL += "&" + keys[i] + "=" + values[i];
    }

    HttpRequest->SetURL(URL);
    HttpRequest->SetVerb(TEXT("GET"));
    HttpRequest->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(this, &ANetwork::OnResponseReceived);
    HttpRequest->ProcessRequest();

    bool wait = true;
    while (wait)
    {
        FHttpResponsePtr response = HttpRequest->GetResponse();
        FHttpResponsePtr httpnull;
        if (response != httpnull)
        {
            if (HttpRequest->GetResponse()->GetContentAsString() != "")
            {
                return HttpRequest->GetResponse()->GetContentAsString();
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

---

On a side note, I'm not sure how to check if an `FHttpResponsePtr` points to a null object. I thought I had it with that code in the while loop, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. Once in a while, the code will break because the response is null when I try to access the content as a string.

Anyone know how to properly check if it is null?

---

### Edit:

Per @TheBrain's answer, here is my revised loop:

```
bool wait = true;
while (wait)
{
    if (HttpRequest->GetStatus() != EHttpRequestStatus::Processing)
    {
        FHttpResponsePtr response = HttpRequest->GetResponse();

        if (response.IsValid())
        {
            return response->GetContentAsString();
        }
        else
            return "INVALID";
    }
}

return "";
```

This causes an infinite loop, however.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a small limit to the response. It looks more like you are fetching the response before it has actually processed the request. You should try to call GetResponse() only after GetStatus() retuns something other than *Processing*.

On the nullpointer check: FHttpResponsePtr is nothing other than a TSharedPtr. As with any TSharedPtr you can use IsValid() **on the pointer itself**. For example, with your code from above:

```
FHttpResponsePtr response = HttpRequest->GetResponse();

if (response != nullptr) { // wrong, the pointer itself is never null!

if (response.IsValid()) { // correct, check for pointer validity

if (response.Get() != nullptr) { // basically the same, but longer
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the misunderstanding. You must ***never*** block the game loop with a while loop like that. So you have two possibilities:

1. You do the check from the while loop, but only once during your actor's tick event.
2. You wait for your callback delegate to fire.

Here is a working code sample using a delegate:

```
void AYourActor::NetworkTest()
{
    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest> HttpRequest = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
    HttpRequest->SetHeader(TEXT("Content-Type"), TEXT("application/json"));
    HttpRequest->SetURL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpRequest->SetVerb(TEXT("GET"));
    HttpRequest->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(this, &AYourActor::OnResponseReceived);
    HttpRequest->ProcessRequest();
}

void AYourActor::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr request, FHttpResponsePtr response, bool didConnect)
{
    UE_LOG(LogExec, Warning, TEXT("Response received %d!"), didConnect);
    UE_LOG(LogExec, Warning, TEXT("Response: %s"), *(response->GetContentAsString()));
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I'll try it in a minute and let you know.

Comment: Please check my edit and let me know if I'm doing something wrong. The loop I made is an infinite loop. The status never changes to completed.

Comment: I adjusted my answer, hope this helps!